# Как конвертировать timestamp в формат YYYY-MM

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня в базе хранится datetime в формате TIMESTAMP. Формат: '2018-01-31T09:13:43+00:00'. Я хотел бы конвертировать его в формат '2018-01' ('YYYY-MM') как это можно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html)

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее:

SQL

```
...to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то Timestamp это long или числовое поле. А то что вы написали это его отображение или формат вывода. Если хотите хранить часть формата в числовом варианте то можете использовать Int месяц и год в полное уместится или же храните строку тогда у вас могут возникнуть проблемы с агрегирование и сравнением все зависит от вашего дальнейшего использования.